# Referencing an outer node from within 'within' block

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

In Capybara, I have several commands to be performed on nodes that share some identical parent node, but in a few occasions, I need to refer to a node completely different. This can be written like this:

```
find('.the .same #part').find('#different_part1').set...
find('.the .same #part').find('.different_part2').set...
find('#a_completely_different_path').set...
find('.the .same #part').find('#different_part3').set...
find('.the .same #part').find('.different_part4').set...
```

I want to use the `within` method to put them together, but for the node that has a completely different path, I need to refer to the context outside of the `within` block. I am not sure how to do it:

```
within('.the .same #part') do
  find('#different_part1').set...
  find('.different_part2').set...
  # find('#a_completely_different_path').set...
  find('#different_part3').set...
  find('.different_part4').set...
end
```

How can I temporarily escape from the effect of `within` and refer to `'#a_completely_different_path'`?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source of [within](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/session.rb#L323),

```
def within(*args)
  new_scope = if args.first.is_a?(Capybara::Node::Base) then args.first else find(*args) end
  begin
    scopes.push(new_scope)
    yield
  ensure
    scopes.pop
  end
end
```

You should probably be able to add a method to `Session` which inverts the functionality, eg.

```
def without
  current_scope = scopes.pop
  yield
ensure
  scopes.push(current_scope)
end
```

That should allow you to do the following:

```
within('.the .same #part') do
  find('#different_part1').set...
  find('.different_part2').set...
  without { find('#a_completely_different_path').set... }
  find('#different_part3').set...
  find('.different_part4').set...
end
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. .

Comment: Your answer directed my to the right place to look into and was a great help, but I came up with a simpler solution. Sorry, but I will move the accepted answer to mine.

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to do it. Use `page.document`.

```
within('.the .same #part') do
  find('#different_part1').set...
  find('.different_part2').set...
  page.document.find('#a_completely_different_path').set...
  find('#different_part3').set...
  find('.different_part4').set...
end
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted so it appears at the top!